# Batch if/else if executes both branches

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement

The following code seems to execute both branches of if and i can't fathom why.

```
@ECHO OFF

set _ERROR=500

If %_ERROR%==500 goto :FIRST
If NOT %_ERROR%==0 If NOT %_ERROR%==500 goto :SECOND

:FIRST
echo FIRST Error code: %_ERROR%

:SECOND
echo SECOND Error code: %_ERROR%
```

Comment: As written, `:FIRST` falls through to `:SECOND`. Not sure what you mean by "*both branches*", only the first `if` gets executed.

Comment: Both echoes are printed, i'm very new to batch scripting and this else-less syntax.

Comment: I've not run it but logically you go to FIRST on error 500. What happens after executing FIRST? The next line of code is echoing SECOND. Maybe exit after echoing the error? Or skip to after SECOND it depends what you're doing with the code after that.

Comment: Yes you are right, I've misinterpreted the way goto statements work, I thought :LABELS can't be accessed without goto, when executing :FIRST it also executes :SECOND, i escaped this by writing goto :END in both :FIRST and :SECOND

Comment: They are not functions like in other scripting languages.

Comment: Luceafărul, I've rolled back your edit, please do not post solutions within the question body, we have an answer area dedicated to the posting of solutions.

Comment: Thanks mate, I haven't been posting that much so I don't really know the correct methods for answering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be using an unnecessary command, you've already omitted the possibility of `%_ERROR%==500` so there's no need to use it again in your code which follows it.

Here's a basic example to show you the structure:

```batch-file
@Rem Turn off printing of issued commands
@Echo Off

Rem Ensure extensions are enabled, [affects GoTo Set and If commands].
SetLocal EnableExtensions

Rem Defined an error variable with a value
Set "_ERROR=500"

Rem Conditions for particular values
If "%_ERROR%" == "500" GoTo FIRST
If Not "%_ERROR%" == "0" GoTo SECOND

Rem Alternatively you could have used this syntax above.
Rem If "%_ERROR%" NEq "0" If "%_ERROR%" Equ "500" (GoTo FIRST) Else GoTo SECOND

Rem Your commands here for %_ERROR% value 0.
Echo Error code: 0&Pause

Rem Quit the script
Exit /B

:FIRST
Rem Your commands here for %_ERROR% value 500.
Echo FIRST Error code: 500&Pause

Rem End the script or go to another label here.
GoTo :EOF

:SECOND
Rem Your commands here for any %_ERROR% value which is not 0 or 500.
Echo SECOND Error code: Not 0 or 500&Pause

Rem End the script or go to another label here.
GoTo :EOF
```

I've `Rem`arked some lines for your information.